# MS Access: How can I requery a report that has 2 subreports?

Tags: ms-access-2010, subreport

I have a report. It has 2 subreports. When I hit F5 to attempt to refresh/requery nothing happens. I have to click on the Report Header section (not part of the subreports) and then hit F5 to refresh. And this doesn't even work every time.

Therefore, I want to give my users a button to refresh the 2 subreports with.

*What I've tried:*

**Requery**

Control Name: subrpt_ProdByLot-A

**Requery**

Control Name: subrpt_ProdByLot-B

**Requery**

Control Name: (intentionally left blank to see if this might make the whole report and its contents requery)

However, this doesn't work. The reports do not refresh/requery and overall nothing changes. If someone has a way to do this maybe even by *not* using a button I'm all ears. I need to give users an easy way to reload the data in the subreports.

Answer (score 0):

You can change how F5 behaves by adding the following to the report module:

I suspect you main report has no datasource which will stop the refresh button in the ribbon (and F5) from doing anything when the main for has teh focus

```
Private Sub Report_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyF5
            KeyCode = 0

            Me.Requery

            Me.mySubReport1.Requery
            Me.mySubReport2.Requery


    End Select

End Sub
```

You could also add a button to the report to run the same requery code lines as in the above snippet.

ie

```
            Me.Requery

            Me.mySubReport1.Requery
            Me.mySubReport2.Requery
```

Comment: Let's say I was being a noob and named my subreports with a dash in them, i.e. subrpt_ProdByLot-CompanyA and subrpt_ProdByLot-CompanyA-Consumption. VBA is inserting a space to the left of the dash, which then changes the name. I tried changing the dashes to underscores, but then nothing happens when I click the button (I'm using your second method). Note - to actually requery the 2 subreports, it looks like I need to click somewhere inside the subreport and then hit F5 and it works. Might there be a way to mimic this action of clicking inside each subreport and hitting F5?

Comment: Reference the control using Me.controls("My control-name-with a dash and spaces").requery    or   Me.[My_control-name].requery     About F5 this is not what I witnessed in my report.